# How to format unallocated space in ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I was installing Ubuntu alongside windows 7 on my laptop. I installed Ubuntu and during installation by mistake formatted my D drive. I installed ubuntu but now I have the remaining free unallocated space from my D drive lying waste. How do I get it back?

Also I want to add more space to my home partition say another 50GB and leave the remaining for windows. How do I do this?

Here is my gparted
[image: http://imgur.com/jv3WzzX]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do this while running Ubuntu. The reason is that you're extended partition (`/dev/sda4`) is currently being used, and so you cannot modify it.

You'll need to boot to an Ubuntu live CD/USB. Once you do that, you can run GParted, extend (resize) the extended partition (`/dev/sda4`), then create more partitions, resize or move around existing partitions, etc within that extended partition.

Answer (score 4):

Just right click on the unallocated space and choose New.  After that, choose partition type, File system type, add it, and then Apply.  See images for detail.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It says "It is not possible to create more than 4 primary partitions. If you want more partitions you should first create an extended partition. Such a partition can contain other partitions. Because an extended partition is also a primary partition it might be necessary to remove a primary partition first."

Comment: Try booting from the Ubuntu live DVD or the [Gparted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php).

Comment: will booting from a bootable usb work?

Comment: It may.  You also may have to create a logical partition instead.

Comment: could you tell more on how would I have to create it?

Comment: Under step 1 in the second image under Create as: choose logical.  The reason to use a live CD is the ability to un-mount the drive, so these operations can happen.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do it on Ubuntu 16.04. I tried to do it via terminal using `parted`, `fdisk`, `sfdisk`, `lsblk` etc. commands (after browsing through various stackoverflow / askubuntu answers) but was unable to do so.

I was not able to see the disk info in lsblk command. What helped me is open up the disk utility program. There you would find the unallocated disks.

[image: Disk Utility Screenshot]

There use the + icon to create a new partitions which would format the drive and there you go. 
`lsblk` will show you the new drive ready to be mounted. :)